# Muslim husband seeing his child with her mother alone in their home

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim, zina, relationships, children

My husband just found out he had a 1 year old child. The mother is non Muslim. He goes over there to see baby alone. I do not like mother’s dialogue with my husband. She is personal with him and way to intimate. She says ThIngs like it’s amazing how much she looks like us and our sleeping beauty. Yes it’s their child but there is no us or our to me in a co parenting plan. She let this child be fatherless for a year and now feels like she has some right to my husband. I haven’t met child yet and that hurts also. Please tell me if it’s haram that he is there alone? I am so lost and don’t know what rights I have. This all seems so wrong to me.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please use meaningful tags! What hinders you telling your husband about your feelings. Be aware that he has the right to visit his child, but not the right to exceed the boundaries of a necessary conversation with the mother of the child.

Comment: It was me who pushed issue for him to see the child there. I didn’t think he would allow her to speak like that without saying anything. This is not about the child at all. It’s all about their dialogue. It is not right that they sit there and text about things like pictures of what she wants to buy the child and where she is going or doing. I will not accept this. If it’s not about baby nothing else should be said.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, if that baby is his and his wives before the marriage of you and him, then you have to accept it, but the fact that she left the child fatherless for a year, breaks my heart. Talk to him about your feelings and may Allah bring peace upon you two.

Comment: I’m not upset about the baby. Or him caring for her. I’m on board and going to love her as mine. If you read what I put, I have a BIG issue with the mother and her boundaries. He is not supposed to be there alone visiting and allowing her to be so intimate with him. Their dialogue is haram

Comment: By the way they were not in a marriage it was a one night stand